# jQuery timepicker com função efetuar em varios input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um código em jQuery que utiliza o timepicker em todos os 35 input. segue abaixo o de segunda:

Abaixo meu `HTML`:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th height="40">Indicador</th>
            <th>Segunda</th>
            <th>Terça</th>
            <th>Quarta</th>
            <th>Quinta</th>
            <th>Sexta</th>
            <th>Sábado</th>
            <th>Domingo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right">Entrada</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="segent" maxlength="5" class="timepicker-entrada ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="terent" maxlength="5" class="timepicker-saida ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quaent" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quient" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sexent" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sabent" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="doment" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right">Saida</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="segsai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker-saida ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tersai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quasai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quisai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sexsai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sabsai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="domsai" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right">Entrada</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="segent2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="terent2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quaent2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quient2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sexent2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sabent2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="doment2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right">Saida</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="segsai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tersai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quasai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quisai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sexsai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sabsai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="domsai2" maxlength="5" class="timepicker ded"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right">Resultado</th>
            <td><input type="time" id="resultseg" class="ded" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="resultter" class="ded" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="resultqua" class="ded" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="resultqui" class="ded" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="resultsex" class="ded" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="resultsab" class="ded" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="resultdom" class="ded" readonly></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Abaixo o código do jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  $('#segsai2').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '7',
    maxTime: '18',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: false,
  });

  $('#segent2').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '7',
    maxTime: '18',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: false,
      change: function(time) {
      var element = $(this), text;
      var timepicker = element.timepicker();
      $('#segsai2').timepicker(
      'option',
      'minTime',
      timepicker.format(time)
      );    
    }
  });

  $('#segsai').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '7',
    maxTime: '18',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: false,
    change: function(time) {
      var element = $(this), text;
      var timepicker = element.timepicker();
      $('#segent2').timepicker(
      'option',
      'minTime',
      timepicker.format(time)
      );
    }
  });

  $('#segent').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '7',
    maxTime: '18',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: false,
    change: function(time) {
      var element = $(this), text;
      var timepicker = element.timepicker();
      $('#segsai').timepicker(
      'option',
      'minTime',
      timepicker.format(time)
      );

    }
  });
});
```

Tem varios problemas.

O primeiro é que o código ficou extremamente grande!! esse é o de segunda, eu copiei ele pra os 7 dias da semana.

O segundo é que preciso que ele faça um calculo para o quinto `input` (resultado), exemplo de segunda:

```
var calc = document.getElementById('calcular');
calc.onclick = function(){
    var segent = parseInt(document.getElementById('segent').value, 10);
    var segsai = parseInt(document.getElementById('segsai').value, 10);
    var segent = parseInt(document.getElementById('segent2').value, 10);
    var segsai = parseInt(document.getElementById('segsai2').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('resultseg').value = (segsai - segent) + (segsai2 - segent2);
}
```

Também fica muito grande se aplicado a todos os dias da semana.

(segsai - segent)+(segsai2 - segent2), e que ele nao deixasse digitar a hora de saída maior que o de entrada ou digitar saída sem que a entrada estivesse preenchida, pois o código jQuery timepicker mostra os possíveis, porem se eu digitar um valor invalido, ele entra mesmo assim.

O terceiro é que preciso que ele retorne o valor no input resultado automático ao preencher o saída, assim:
(se valor menor ou igual a 4 retorna o valor 1, se valor maior que 4 e menor ou igual a 8 retorna 2, se maior ou igual a 8 retorna 3).

Estou começando a estudar jQuery e javascript, porem sou muito novato ainda, e não estou conseguindo resolver isso.

Obrigado!

Comment: Atenção que tem uma `"` a mais na primeira Saida no primeiro `<input>` em `class="timepicker-saida ded""`. Toda essa lógica feita por `id` nunca será escalável em dimensão. Terá que a fazer por classes.

Comment: concertado, eu utilizei id, pois fiz uma "gambiarra" para poder funcionar pois não consegui fazer com que o sistema entenda que eu quero efetuar somas entre o primeiro <td> da primeira <tr> com o primeiro <td> da segunda <tr> e assim por diante..